# What exactly does the limiter do in FSK demodulators?

Tags: wireless, digital-communications, dsp

I wonder what exactly the limiter does in FSK demodulators.

1. What are the advantages?
2. Could it be just a saturation in ADC or fixed-pointing stages?

Comment: Probably should spend some time reading [this](https://w7ay.net/site/Technical/RTTY%20Demodulators/Contents/am.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What does limiter exactly do in FSK demodulators?*

It does the same job whether the transmission is FSK or regular broadcast FM. A normal **FM** radio receiver can use **AM** demodulation techniques such as an envelope detector but first, it has to ensure that the frequencies in the band of interest are all amplitude controlled: -

[image]

Image from [FM capture effect](https://www.cdt21.com/design_guide/fm-capture-effect/).

First it uses an amplitude limiter then, it uses a tuned circuit to convert the limiter's flat spectral amplitude into a spectrum with slope. Then it can use an AM detector. This overall is called an FM slope detector and it relies on the spectrum being "flattened" by the limiter.

The limiter also does other things like rejecting local AM carriers or weaker signals thus maintaining a high-degree of fidelity in the detected signal: -

[image]

The limiter also acts "like an" AGC (call it automatic level control) in that anything received across the full spectrum is converted to the same amplitude thus making it easier to design the rest of the circuitry.

Comment: thanks, Andy, but what if we use a correlator as an FSK demodulator (like the first one used in ADF7020)?

Comment: @Ali I don't understand the relevance of your comment to your original question. I mean, the ADF7020 has a limiter so what gives?

Comment: I mean I don't get why we use limiters when we use correlators for FSK demodulators (no FM-to-AM here)

Comment: @Ali a cheap, available and practical correlator was not something on the horizon when FM came into existence. The ADF7200 **does have** a limiter so I'm really not sure where this conversation is going. If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.